# Simplifying $10 \binom{29}{0} + 9\binom{30}{1} + 8 \binom{31}{2} + \ldots + 2\binom{37}{8} + 1\binom{38}{9}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, contest-math, binomial-coefficients

In trying to solve a probability problem from an old math contest:
https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1987_AIME_Problems/Problem_13

I had reduced the crux of the problem to calculating/simplifying$$10 \binom{29}{0} + 9\binom{30}{1} + 8 \binom{31}{2} + \ldots + 
2\binom{37}{8} + 1\binom{38}{9},$$which I'm not sure how to simplify further. Could anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Calvin Lin asks me to explain how I got my expression. The total number of ways to order $40$ distinct numbers is $40!$, so that will be our denominator. So let's calculate the numerator. Without loss of generality let our numbers in some order be $1$, $2$, $\ldots$, $39$, $40$. We are counting the total number of configurations where:

1. $r_{20}$ is greater than the other first $29$ numbers i.e. $r_1$, $r_2$, $\ldots$, $r_{18}$, $r_{19}$, $r_{21}$, $r_{22}$, $\ldots$, $r_{29}$, $r_{30}$.
2. $r_{20}$ is less than $r_{31}$.

So $r_{20}$ has to be at least $30$ and is at most $39$. Let's go case by case:

- $r_{20} = 30$: The first $29$ numbers (where is $r_{20}$ omitted) have to be selected from $1$, $2$, $\ldots$, $28$, $29$, hence $29!$ ways to select and order. Then there's $10$ choices for $r_{31}$, and then $9!$ choices for the last $9$ numbers.
- $r_{20} = 31$: The first $29$ numbers (where is $r_{20}$ omitted) have to be selected from $1$, $2$, $\ldots$, $28$, $29$, $30$, hence $30 \cdot 29 \cdots 3 \cdot 2$ ways to select and order. Then there's $9$ choices for $r_{31}$, and then $9!$ choices for the last $9$ numbers.
- And so forth$\ldots$
- $r_{20} = 39$: The first $29$ numbers (where is $r_{20}$ omitted) have to be selected from $1$, $2$, $\ldots$, $37$, $38$, hence $38 \cdot 37 \cdots 11 \cdot 10$ ways to select and order. There's only $1$ choice for $r_{31}$ and that's $r_{31} = 40$, and again there's $9!$ choices for the last $9$ numbers.

So our numerator is$$(29!)(10)(9!) + (30 \cdot 29 \cdots 3 \cdot 2)(9)(9!) + \ldots + (37 \cdot 36 \cdots 10 \cdot 9)(2)(9!) + (38 \cdot 37 \cdots 11 \cdot 10)(1)(9!) = (29!)(9!)\left(10 + 9{{30}\over{1}} + 8{{31 \cdot 20}\over{2 \cdot 1}} + 7{{32 \cdot 31 \cdot 30}\over{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}}  + \ldots + 1{{38 \cdots 30}\over{9 \cdots 1}}\right) = (29!)(9!)\left(10 \binom{29}{0} + 9\binom{30}{1} + 8 \binom{31}{2} + \ldots + 1\binom{38}{9}\right).$$So the expression we want to calculate/simplify is$$10 \binom{29}{0} + 9\binom{30}{1} + 8 \binom{31}{2} + \ldots + 1\binom{38}{9}.$$Again, any help would be well-appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at that calculation (and what your denominator is like)? Reading the solution, they seemed to have taken a different approach to re-interpret the condition to make the calculation almost-immediate.

Comment: Thanks @CalvinLin, I've shown my work (and in the process realized I made a mistake in getting the expression in my original post, I've edited in the correct expression we want to find).

Comment: Try the Hockey stick identity (applied twice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1:** Use the Hockey stick identity twice.

First application: It states that $ { 29\choose 0 } + \ldots { 29 + i \choose i } = { 29 + i + 1 \choose i }$.
Second application: Sum up the first application for $ i = 0$ to 9 via the Hockey stick identity again to get $ \sum_{i=0}^9 { 29 + i +1 \choose i } = {40 \choose 9 }$.

**Approach 2:** Find a combinatorial identity now that you know the expression is "nice".
You could modify the combinatorial identity for Hockey stick identity.

Answer (score 6):

So we want the value of
$$\sum_{n=0}^9 (10-n)\binom{29+n}{n}$$
Note that $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=0+x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+\ldots$ and $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{30}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{29+n}{n}x^n$. Hence, our desired sum is the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the cauchy product of the two sequences.

This is the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\cdot \frac{1}{(1-x)^{30}}$$
$$=\frac{x}{(1-x)^{32}}$$
$$=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{31+n}{n}x^n$$
Hence, the coefficient of $x^{10}$ is $\binom{40}{9}$

Comment: it seem there is a little typo in the summation , there must have been writen "i" instead of "n"

Comment: @Bulbasaur Thanks for catching

Answer (score 1):

Let us define $b=10$ and $a=30$, then you can obtain a generalized formula:

$$\sum _{i=1}^b i \binom{a+b-i-1}{b-i}=\binom{a+b}{b-1}{\color{lightgrey}{=\frac{\Gamma (a+b+1)}{\Gamma (a+2) \Gamma (b)}}}$$

Here $\Gamma (z)$ is the [Euler Gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html). You may verify it using Mathematica by:

```
FullSimplify[Sum[i*Binomial[a + b - 1 - i, b - i], {i, 1, b}]];
```

Inserting your concrete values leads to $273438880$.

An interesting reference might be the paper ["Some Formulas for Sums of
Binomial Coefficients and Gamma Functions"](http://www.m-hikari.com/imf-password2007/13-16-2007/garrappaIMF13-16-2007.pdf), which deals with connections between the Gamma function and sums of binomial coefficients.

Comment: There's no need to pull in the Euler Gamma function. The RHS is $ { a+b \choose b-1}$, which suggests there's some combinatorial identity going on .

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you for this hint.